# Save whole input in integer array (read with getchar)

Tags: c, getchar

I'm only allowed to use the stdio.h library. So I want to read the user input with getchar until the first "/" and then want to save the read input in an integer array. Checking the input out of the while-loop, i recognized that only the last string is safed.

For example I type in "test/hello", I want to safe "test" in the integer array called "safe" so that I can work with it  out of the while-loop too.

I have checked the input out of the while-loop with "putchar(safe[count]);" but the only safed input is the letter "t". (Based on the example above)

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int count;
    char i;
    int safe[50];

    int main() {
        while (1) {
            i = getchar();
            count = 0;
            if (i == '/')
                break;
            safe[count] = i;
        }
        // putchar(safe[count]);
     }
```

Comment: You do not increase `count`

Comment: You should also add in a check to never get to `count >= 50`. Also why do you store the chars as ints?

Comment: Why set `count` to zero inside the loop? It will now just set `safe[0]` to i. You must increment it: `safe[count++]= i;`

Comment: In addition to breaking out if `count` reaches 50, you should also break out when `i` equals `EOF`. Also, `safe[]` can use type `char` instead of `int` to save space.

Answer (score 0):

See the comments as to the why, but the following is correct:

```
int main() {
    count= 0;
    while (count<49) {
        i = getchar();
        if (i == '/')
            break;
        safe[count++] = i;
    }
    safe[count]= '\0';
 }
```